# Multiple active projects under single config? Or, multiple active configurations?

Tags: gcloud

I have a set of clusters split between two projects, 1 and 2. Currently, need to use `gcloud init` to switch between the two projects. Is there any possibility of having both projects active under the single configuration? Or, is it possible to have two configurations simultaneously active? I would hate to have to use `init` every time to switch between the two. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gcloud init`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init) should only be used to (re)initialize `gcloud` on a host. The only time I ever use it is when I install `gcloud` on a new machine.

`gcloud` uses a global config that can be manipulated with the [`gcloud config`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config) command. IMO (I've been using GCP for 9 years) the less you use `gcloud config`, the better for your experience.

I think you're much better placed specifying config explicitly with `gcloud` commands.

**Every** `gcloud` command can include e.g.:

- `--project=${PROJECT}` to specify the project to use
- `--account=${ACCOUNT}` to specify the `gcloud auth`'d account to use
- `--region=${REGION}` or `--zone=${ZONE}` or `--location=${LOCATION}`

etc.

Using `gcloud` commands and explicitly setting flags to specific the project, account, location etc. makes it trivial to flip between these and often (though not always) in a more intentional way.